# Display value from dictionary after using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, plist, nspredicate

I am currently using NSPredicate to search if a certain key has a certain value in plist, if it matches, I want it to display one of the values in the dictionary, not the entire dictionary, but the way I am using NSPredicate returns me the whole dictionary of items. May I know how to do that?

Let's say my plist looks like this:

```
    Root (Array)
     Item 0 (Dictionary)
          Name (String)
          Number (String)
          Address (Dictionary)
               First Address (Array)
                    Item 0 (Dictionary)
                         Block (String)            Value: 1234
                         Postal Code (String)
                         Unit Number (String)
                         Street Name (String)      Value: King Street
               Second Address (Array)
                        Item 1 (Dictionary)
                         Block (String)
                         Postal Code (String)
                         Unit Number (String)
                         Street Name (String)
     Item 1 (Dictionary)
          and so on...
```

My NSPredicate goes like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Block == '1234'"];
NSArray *predicateArray = [blockStage filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The NSPredicate returns me all the values in Item 0, but I want to only display the value of "Street Name", which is "King Street". How do I go about doing that???

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetch request will return all objects from the initial array that match your predicate. So if your initial array contains objects at the level of `Item 0`, this is what is returned.

If you only want to display the street name afterwards then you will need to pick this out of the returned object(s) using whatever `objectForKey` statements are necessary. You'll probably need some additional logic to determine which address (first or second) matches your predicate, since the keys are the same.

If your keys are really as described in the plist example above, these are not key value coding compliant. See [Key-Value Coding Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE) for details.

Comment: Well, as long as the block value is "1234", it shall display the street name. I tried using objectForKey, but it doesn't respond as I am using NSArray *predicateArray.

Comment: What do you see if you do `NSLog(@"%@",predicateArray);` after your fetch request?

Comment: It displays:
{
Block = "1234";
Postal Code = "Value";
Unit Number = "Value";
Street Name = "King Street";
}

That is what it displays when I don't use objectForKey. Using objectForKey crashes the app.

Comment: `[predicateArray objectForKey:@"Street Name"];` causes a crash? I wonder if you are allowed spaces in your key names? It doesn't seem a good idea to have spaces in there, I've never seen keys like that but that is a guess.

Comment: Actually what you have posted above looks like the log from a single dictionary rather than an array, is that the full log?

Comment: Hi jrturton, it works like a charm when I used valueForKey. Thank you so much!!!!! :D Appreciate it lots! Thanks!